Связывание SQL Server и PostgreSQL
Обстановка до:
SQL Server, содержащий в себе две базы данных, условно: база с данными и база с процедурами, которые обращаются к базе с данными.
Обстановка после:
База с данными переезжает на Postgres, и с этим ничего нельзя поделать. База с процедурами остается на SQL Server и она довольно мобильна.
Проблема:
В текущей обстановке имеется несколько сложностей в общении между базами:

Скорость запросов на SQL Server стала значительно ниже из-за обращения к Postgres;
Требуется переписывать почти все процедуры для замены источника данных;

Основной вопрос:
Какие действия можно предпринять для решения проблем разделения баз данных?
В данный момент я выбираю либо простую заменой источника данных и мирюсь с тем, что процедуры и запросы выполняются в несколько раз дольше (в некоторых случаях, вместо 0.2 с. запрос выполняется 4 минуты). Либо настраиваю репликацию данных из Postgres на SQL Server.
Может я что-то ещё упускаю, и есть способы проще и эффективнее.

Как насчёт Babelfish?

А в чем проблема перенести процедуры на PostgreSQL? Мне кажется, что в данной ситуации Вы сами себе наступаете на "фаберже". Потом мучаться будете, что сервера - два разных. Да уже мучаетесь. Потратьте немного времени, мигрируйте и успокойтесь.

Планировщики запросов и оптимизаторы обоих серверов тихо плачут без работы... Переписывайте процедуры на Pgplsql - другого решения нет.

Самый быстрый способ обращения в PostgreSQL из MSSQL- это RPC.
Подготовили запрос для pg, вызвали. Так можно протолкнуть очень большой скрипт. На практике проталкивал json размером 30 мегабайт.
EXECUTE('select ....') AT PGLinkedServer

Но в целом архитектурно всё очень криво, переходите на pg полностью, отказывайтесь от mssql.
